# Placeholder notation for separate HTML files for creating small portions of web pages and replacing placeholders with data values

Tags: javascript, html, string, dom

Currently I am using text like "rusername" "rpassword" or "rdate" and then replace using an appropriate string replace function, e.g.

```
htmlstring=htmlstring.replace(/rusername/g,object.username);
```

it is a confusing notation when the project size grows. for worlds like rreply rratio etc. when I use :username html editor gives errors that I wouldn't want to see, because the editor thinks I'll directly use the html rather than replacing it. what kind of notation should I use for text to be replaced? it should look legitimate for html designers, {username} is no good, is there a common format for it? What do you suggest?

There might be many valid ways, so please don't hesitate to answer in any way.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend against doing string replace at all, and instead use spans with ids. It will also be much faster.

```
<div>
    Hello, <span id="username"><span>!
</div>
```

And then your script can look like:

```
document.getElementById("username").innerHTML = object.username;
```

Comment: when I add multiple items on a page, span ID's coincide and I will need to give unique span Id's for each span, like spanid+datarowid, which creates new problems

Comment: If your pages are really that complex, you might want to consider using server rendered pages instead of static html pages that load data via javascript.